# Finding ideals with a given norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

> Find all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$ with norm $12$.

I know that we must have that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]/I = 12$ for any ideal $I$ that has norm $12$ but I am not sure on how to expand upon this. I tried using the fact that $N(I) = \sqrt{\frac{D(I)}{D(\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}])}}$ but I am unsure how to find $D(I)$ since we do not know the basis of $I$.

Could someone please help me with this question. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to find ideals of norm $3$ and $2$, for example (or to show that none exist)?